# UIButton Global Appearance

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want the same look for my UIButtons throughout the application. I tried to use UIAppearance protocol but it does not expose any interesting methods for UIButton. I want to change the textColor and the font for all the UIButtons.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can suggest you to read [Designing for iOS: Taming UIButton](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33427366406/designing-for-ios-taming-uibutton) and [Five Tips for Creating Stylish UIButtons](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/custom-uibutton_iphone/). It will provide you a good overview of how to make customization of UIBUtton, including the properties you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subclass `UIButton` and override one of the custom initialization or convenience factory methods. Something like this:

```
@interface MyCustomButton: UIButton
@end

@implementation MyCustomButton

+ (UIButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type
{
    UIButton *b = [super buttonWithType:type];
    b.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    b.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FooBar-Bold" size:3.14]; // today's Pi day
    return b;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess after subclassing I have to go to every occurrence of UIButton and change its super class to MyCustomButton. Is there any easier way to say that all of my UIButtons will derive from MyCustomButton. I guess there is no easier way. Thanks!